# Getting axios CORS error in Quasar app while using json-server to fetch data

Tags: cors, json-server

I have installed json server in my quasar app, Now I am trying to get data from db.json using axios. But I am getting the following error :

[image]

devServer looks like in quasar.config.js:

```js
devServer: {
  server: {
    type: 'http'
  },
  port: 8080,
  open: true // opens browser window automatically
},
```

My codes from script are :

```js
methods: {
  getList() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/shipments').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
},
```

It seems, I don't Have any json-server.json file in directory :

[image]

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "frontend-challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Frontend Coding Challenge",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "********",
  "author": "ChallengeTeam",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "json-server db.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a json-server issue. Show your json-server config

Comment: I don't have any json-server config file, I have shared the dir image in my question

Comment: What is hosting the server on localhost:3000?

Comment: I am not sure, I am just running npm run server and the it's hosting the server

Answer (score 0):

You should disable CORS on your API on localhost:3000.

Create a new file in your projects root folder named `json-server.json`, and add this to it:

```js
// json-server.json
{
  "noCors": true
}
```

Or, if you don't need to access your dev server on the network, change the dev server host

```js
// quasar.config.js
devServer: {
  host: "localhost", 
  server: {
    type: 'http'
  },
  port: 8080,
  open: true // opens browser window automatically
},
```

Comment: I need dev server on the network, How can I disable CORS in API on localhost:3000

Comment: We don't know what server you are running. Show your package.json

Comment: I have updated the question with package.json

Comment: it's json-server `"dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.2"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: '',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': ''
      }
    }
  },
```

return changeOrigin to false